# How to add PHP in PHP

Tags: php

Forgive me, my PHP skills are rough to say the least, I am trying to pass PHP into PHP see below

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[tab name="Info"]
<span>Address:<?php echo get_field('address'); ?></span>
[/tab][end_tabset]'); ?>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I have been searching everywhere, but nothing seems to work.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php

echo do_shortcode('[tab name="Info"]
<span>Address:' . get_field('address') . '</span>
[/tab][end_tabset]');
```

Comment: To clarify, [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) does not interpret PHP code in the string. It only interprets WordPress short codes such as `[tab]`. Also, you were closing the string with the single quotes around `address` in the call to `get_field`, but that is solved by extracting the PHP function call outside of the string.